# How to get Repository Interface object back from SimpleJpaRepository<T,ID> object with proxy resolution

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-aop

Repository Class

```
@Repository
public interface AllFileRepository extends JpaRepository<AllFile, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT a From AllFile a where a.guid = :guid")
    AllFile findByGuid(@Param("guid") String guid);
}
```

Service Class

```
@Service
@Data
public class PipelineService implements Serializable {
    /**
     *
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Autowired
    AllFileRepository allFileRepository;
}
```

Creating object SimpleJpaRepository<AllFile, Long>

```
PipelineService pipelineService = new PipelineService();

void methodX() {
    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext applicationContext = (AnnotationConfigApplicationContext) 
    ApplicationContextUtils.getApplicationContext();
    AutowireCapableBeanFactory autowireCapableBeanFactory = 
        applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
    autowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBean(pipelineService);
    JpaRepository<AllFile, Long> jpaRepository = (SimpleJpaRepository<AllFile, Long>) 
        AopProxyUtils.getSingletonTarget(pipelineService.getAllFileRepository());

    // (AllFileRepository) jpaRepository casting causes ClassCastException
 }
```

Exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository cannot be cast to ....repository.AllFileRepository
```

How to get an object of AllFileRepository interface? where I can access `findByGuid("");`

**UPDATE**

I am able to get the object of `SimpleJpaRepository<AllFile, Long>` belonging to interface AllFileRepository which inturn extends JpaRepository

```
public void initialize() {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext applicationContext = (AnnotationConfigApplicationContext) ApplicationContextUtils
                .getApplicationContext();
        EntityManager em = applicationContext.getBean(EntityManager.class);
        AllFileRepository allFileRepository = new JpaRepositoryFactory(em).getRepository(AllFileRepository.class);
        allFileRepository.findByGuid(""); // Method is accessible here but the object is proxy
        SimpleJpaRepository<AllFile, Long> simpleJpaRepository = (SimpleJpaRepository<AllFile, Long>) (AopProxyUtils
                .getSingletonTarget(allFileRepository)); // But proxy resolution yeilds SimpleJpaRepository cannot
                                                         // explicitly cast to AllFileRepository
        ((AllFileRepository) simpleJpaRepository).findByGuid(""); // class
                                                                  // org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository
                                                                  // cannot be cast to class
                                                                  // com.example.spingaoprepository.repository.AllFileRepository
                                                                  // (org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository
                                                                  // and
                                                                  // com.example.spingaoprepository.repository.AllFileRepository
                                                                  // are in unnamed module of loader 'app'

    }
```

Here is a link to sample [program](https://github.com/raghudinkavijaykumar/springaoprepository.git)

Comment: The class needs to be serialized and sent out of JVM to a different machine where it can be reinitialized. hence I am providing object creation logic from the application context

Comment: Please be so kind as to provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) project on GitHub. If I can reproduce your problem, I think I can suggest a solution. After just parsing your code in my head, not being able to compile and run it, it looks as if you are trying to cast `AllFileRepository` to `SimpleJpaRepository`, but actually `AllFileRepository` only extends `JpaRepository`, not `SimpleJpaRepository`.

Comment: @kriegaex yes you are right, casting will not work, i have provided a sample code

Comment: In your repository I see no class implementing `AllFileRepository`. So how can you expect anything to be castable to it? Spring seems to find the best matching implementation for interfaces `AllFileRepository` extends and that seems to be `SimpleJpaRepository`. Like I said before, that class does not implement `AllFileRepository`. You ought to provide your own implementation, so Spring can find it.

Comment: I had forgot to add the `@Query` for the `AllFileRepository` method `findByGuid("")`. Generally speaking for a repository interface, I never created my own class implementing it. lets say, if i create a class implementing `AllFileRepository`. i will have to write its query implementation (i.e creating Query from EntityManger and executing it ) also right for all its methods and essentially methods of JpaRepository? Correct me if am wrong.

Comment: is there any additional class created by spring data jpa, for all of my `@Repository` classes, or somehow `SimpleJpaRespository<T, ID>` knows these? Essentially i am unable to answer this myself....

Comment: @kriegaex I have provided an example where, i am not providing any custom implementation for AllFileRepository, but still i get an object of it from Spring belonging to SimpleJpaRepository. I may be wrong somehere.

Comment: The dynamic proxy actually implements `AllFileRepository`, but its target class `SimpleJpaRespository` does not if you do not provide a custom implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no use in trying to cast incompatible types into each other. This is not a Spring problem, it is Java basics. I already told you how to solve that in Spring, too: You need to provide a class actually implementing `AllFileRepository` and make sure Spring Data JPA uses it as a repository instead of the interface. In order to do that, you need to

- change the interface annotation from `@Repository` to `@NoRepositoryBean`,
- create class `@Repository AllFileRepositoryImpl` and there provide an implementation of `AllFile findByGuid(String guid)` doing something meaningful.

Then you can easily cast the way you want because your proxy's target object will be an `AllFileRepositoryImpl` instance.

I sent you a [pull request](https://github.com/raghudinkavijaykumar/springaoprepository/pull/1) which you just need to accept. The classes changed in the relevant [commit @5705cbb](https://github.com/raghudinkavijaykumar/springaoprepository/pull/1/commits/5705cbbc57dfb58173e5ab8bb5b22a666d4a4a95) look as follows:

```java
package com.example.spingaoprepository.repository;

import com.example.spingaoprepository.model.AllFile;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.data.repository.NoRepositoryBean;

@NoRepositoryBean
public interface AllFileRepository extends JpaRepository<AllFile, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT a From AllFile a where a.guid = :guid")
    AllFile findByGuid(@Param("guid") String guid);
}
```

```java
package com.example.spingaoprepository.repository;

import com.example.spingaoprepository.model.AllFile;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

@Repository
public class AllFileRepositoryImpl extends SimpleJpaRepository<AllFile, Long> implements AllFileRepository {
  public AllFileRepositoryImpl(EntityManager em) {
    super(AllFile.class, em);
  }

  @Override
  public AllFile findByGuid(String guid) {
    System.out.println("Finding AllFile by GUID " + guid);
    return null;
  }
}
```

```java
package com.example.spingaoprepository.serializable;

import com.example.spingaoprepository.repository.AllFileRepository;
import com.example.spingaoprepository.service.PipelineService;
import com.example.spingaoprepository.utils.ApplicationContextUtils;

import org.springframework.aop.framework.AopProxyUtils;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.AutowireCapableBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

public class PipelineConfigurer {
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext = ApplicationContextUtils.getApplicationContext();
    private PipelineService pipelineService = applicationContext.getBean(PipelineService.class);

    public void initialize() {
        AutowireCapableBeanFactory autowireCapableBeanFactory = applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
        autowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBean(pipelineService);
        AllFileRepository allFileRepository = (AllFileRepository) AopProxyUtils
                .getSingletonTarget(pipelineService.getAllFileRepository());
        allFileRepository.findByGuid("XY-123");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are instantiating your PipelineService using the `new` keyword and then manually getting the Spring context in your methodX().

In principle, of course you 'could' do it all manually without Spring. But   given both your repository and service are Spring beans, then it's  better to let Spring handle the bean lifecyle. It's certainly easier anyway.

As PipelineService is a Spring bean, you should really make any class that uses it Spring aware too. So just annotate the class that with a Spring annotation like `@Component`, `@Service`, or perhaps `@RestController` if it's a controller.

If you insist on creating the bean manually then try -

```
 ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
 PipelineService pipelineService = context.getBean(PipelineService.class);
```

Comment: I will add more info to the question. I need the proxy objects to be resolved to real objects.

Answer (score 0):

Using @Autowired you are injecting an object implementing AllFileRepository. This singleton was created at startup hence you can just use is with `allFileRepository.findByGuid("");`

Comment: I cannot autowire, its outside of spring context classes, sorry for the confusion. I would never have tried to autowire manually

Comment: Why don't you just make whatever class uses it a Spring component?

Comment: The class needs to be serialized and sent out of JVM to a different machine where it can be reinitialized. hence I am providing object creation logic from the application context

Comment: I've updated my answer to show how to get the context/bean manually :)